# There exists $x\in M$ such that $Ann(x)=\langle lcm(x_1,x_2) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit which is also a PID. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. For $m\in M$, we define
$$Ann(m)=\{r\in R:r\cdot m=0\}.$$
Also, if $Ann(m)=\langle c \rangle$ for some $c\in R\backslash \{0\}$, $c$ is called the order of the element $m$.

I want to prove the following:

Suppose $x_1,x_2\in M$ are such that $Ann(x_1)=\langle c_1 \rangle$ and $Ann(x_2)=\langle c_2 \rangle$ for $c_1,c_2\in R\backslash \{0\}$. Then there exists $x\in M$ such that $Ann(x)=\langle lcm(c_1,c_2) \rangle$. ($lcm$ denotes the least common multiple).

Any ideas on how to approach this? I thought this would not be hard to prove but I am quite stuck.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How would you prove it for $R=\mathbb Z?$ How would you define the LCM in a PID? Show us some work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If the ring were $\mathbb{Z}$ then we would have an abelian group. I know a proof in that case, but it relies in the factorization in primes of the orders of the elements. I am not sure how to generalize that.

Comment: Put your work into your question. Think about basic things, like, why does LCM make sense in a PID?